# rails 3.2 nested route How expression loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I would like to make simple expression below case
routes.rb

```
 namespace :post do
    namespace :p01 do
      resources :p9_posts
    end
  end
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p01 do
      resources :p8_posts
    end
  end
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p01 do
      resources :p7_posts
    end
  end
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p01 do
      resources :p6_posts
    end
  end
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p01 do
      resources :p5_posts
    end
  end
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p01 do
      resources :p4_posts
    end
  end
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p01 do
      resources :p3_posts
    end
  end
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p01 do
      resources :p2_posts
    end
  end
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p01 do
      resources :p1_posts
    end
  end
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p01 do
      resources :p0_posts
    end
  end
```

I would like to make simple expression to use loop
how can I do that

and also below too

```
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p10 do
      resources :posts do
        resources :comments
      end
    end
  end
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p09 do
      resources :posts do
        resources :comments
      end
    end
  end
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p08 do
      resources :posts do
        resources :comments
      end
    end
  end
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p07 do
      resources :posts do
        resources :comments
      end
    end
  end
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p06 do
      resources :posts do
        resources :comments
      end
    end
  end
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p05 do
      resources :posts do
        resources :comments
      end
    end
  end
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p04 do
      resources :posts do
        resources :comments
      end
    end
  end
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p03 do
      resources :posts do
        resources :comments
      end
    end
  end
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p02 do
      resources :posts do
        resources :comments
      end
    end
  end
  namespace :post do
    namespace :p01 do
      resources :posts do
        resources :comments
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: can you provide more details on what you are trying to achieve ? why do you need so many namespaces ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rewrite it like that:

```
namespace :post do
  namespace :p01 do
    9.downto(0) { |i| resources "p#{i}_posts".to_sym }
  end
end
```